# Django Rest Framework JWT user register/login concept

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm creating a Login/Register API with Django Rest Framework which is consumed by my frontend, using JWT to authenticate and there are some basic things I can't seem to understand and maybe someone can help me out.

I created an endpoint to register a user (a POST to `/users/`). At first I was getting a `"Authentication credentials were not provided."` if I tried sending a request using Postman (on Django API GUI it would work normally I guess because they already send the correct authentication). However, when I think about it, it comes to me that he doesn't have the credentials yet since he's not registered and logged in, so its JWT wasn't created, so I added `permission_classes = (AllowAny, )` to my APIView. But then it allows anyone to use the API, therefore anyone would be able to send a PATCH request to update some info without sending the JWT in the request. Anyone have any idea on how to handle that?

I think somehow I'm lacking some kind of concept about authentication. Maybe I need one exclusively for communicating my backend and frontend that will be used to register a user and the users JWT will be used to perform the other actions?

If needed, I can provide other informations about my architecture or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** As per your description,

> I created an endpoint to register a user (a POST to /users/). At first I was getting a "Authentication credentials were not provided." if I tried sending a request using Postman (on Django API GUI it would work normally I guess because they already send the correct authentication).

You have to understand that since the api is a user registraion api, the permission class should always be set as `permission_class = (AllowAny,)`, but you set `permission_class = (IsAuthenticated,)` in your view, so django expecting a proper authentication credential(a JWT token as you are using JWT) to make sure the requested user is authenticated. Thats why you are getting a `"Authentication credentials were not provided."` exception in your `POST /users/` api.

**Second**, as you said later,

> However, when I think about it, it comes to me that he doesn't have the credentials yet since he's not registered and logged in, so its JWT wasn't created, so I added `permission_classes = (AllowAny, )` to my APIView

its obvious when a user registering himself/herself, then he/she will not have any credentials(JWT token).

**then you said,**

> But then it allows anyone to use the API, therefore anyone would be able to send a PATCH request to update some info without sending the JWT in the request.

From these lines it seems that you are using single api view to Create(POST) and partial update(PATCH) of user. What you have to do is to make separate api views. That is one api view for `Create/Register(POST)` user and set `permission_classes = (AllowAny, )` and another api view to `Update(PATCH)` user and set `permission_class = (IsAuthenticated,)`. I think this will solve your problem.

**EDITION**: Now for better understanding how permission works in django rest framework, lets check this [the way permission works in django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It does explain a lot to me! Do you know if I would have to actually different APIViews or if there's a way to maybe override just the post method to `AllowAny`? I'm using `viewsets.ModelViewSet` and just setting the serializer, queryset and permission_classes.

Comment: Better you create separate API views(generic) , otherwise if you want to use viewsets  and want to provide separate permission for methods, then check this link https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1067